# Switch focus/activate another Application after opening it

Tags: c#, winapi, automation, com, photoshop

I added an "Edit with Photoshop" button and succeeded opening Photoshop with a file using this code:

```
Type PhotoshopType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Photoshop.Application");
object PhotoshopInst = Activator.CreateInstance(PhotoshopType);                    
PhotoshopType.InvokeMember("Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, PhotoshopInst, new object[1] { "c:\files\image.jpg" });
```

But I am failing to activate (give focus to) Photoshop so the user does not have to switch manually.
Any idea on how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically a use-case for the [UIAutomation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) technology. Here is a sample C# console app that does this:

```
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Photoshop.Application"));
instance.Open(@"c:\files\image.jpg");

// add a COM reference to "UIAutomationClient"
// uncheck "Embed interop types" in the UIAutomationClient Reference properties (or redeclare the ids manually)
var uia = new UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation();
var root = uia.GetRootElement();

// find Photoshop window (it's a top level window)
var ps = root.FindFirst(UIAutomationClient.TreeScope.TreeScope_Children,
    uia.CreateAndCondition(
            uia.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId, "window"),
            uia.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "Photoshop")
            )
    );

if (ps != null)
{
    // this is not to be confused with Win32's SetFocus API
    // it does a lot more
    ps.SetFocus();
}
```

To determine how to search for Photoshop, you can use the [Inspect tool from Windows SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) and you will see something like this:

[image]

Where the "localized control type" is "window" and the ClassName" is "Photoshop".

Comment: I had to change "window" to "ventana" in UIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId, since my Windows is in Spanish.

Comment: I had to install the old Win 8.1 SDK since in the last Win 10/11 SDK, inspect.exe was not present: https://developer.microsoft.com/es-mx/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

Comment: @MundoPeter - inspect.exe is present on all Windows SDK including the latest (I have it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64` for example) but maybe it requires to check some options during install. You can also use https://accessibilityinsights.io/ which is the newer tool. For the localization issue, you can use `UIA_CustomControlTypeId ` instead and check for `UIA_WindowControlTypeId` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-controltype-ids