# What's the correct way to bring a window to the front

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've been trying multiple ways of bringing a window into focus and on top of other windows.

I've tried [`SetForegroundWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow), [`BringWindowToTop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-bringwindowtotop), [`SetActiveWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setactivewindow). None of these work consistently.

How can I simply make it so that a window that I want to be in focus, becomes on top of all other windows and is focused? Why is this so difficult?

Comment: Make sure you check the return code.  If the function indicates failure, check [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) for detailed information.

Comment: @Elijay sadly the functions are not failing. They are just not doing anything.

Comment: That's very odd then that the functions return **success**, yet are not doing anything.  Puzzling.

Comment: You can call UIAutomation's SetFocus here in C# but can easily  be done in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71869106/403671

Comment: *"Why is this so difficult?"* - If it were easy and everyone could do it, then inevitably everyone would. You would not be able to keep using your computer faster than you can say *"Blueberry Pie"*. The rules that are in place are there to *help* the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process needs to satisfy a few conditions for it to be able to set the foreground window.
This is to prevent applications from stealing focus - which is a very bad user experience.

Imagine you're writing an email, and halfway through it your application decides now would be a good time to push a window into foreground. As you're typing suddenly the focused window would instantly change and your keypresses would now be sent to your program instead of the mail program. Not only could this cause all sorts of havoc (the keys you pressed are now sent to your program, so hotkeys might get triggered, dialogs dismissed, etc...) - but it would also be a really frustrating experience for the user (especially for less technically-inclined people).

That is the reason why `SetForegroundWindow()` & similar functions sometimes won't push your window to the foreground, but still report success. Your window will still flash in the task bar though, so users know that something happened in your application.

---

##### SetForegroundWindow

The exact list of conditions that need to be met for [`SetForegroundWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) to work [are detailed in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow#remarks):

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window.
> A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The foreground process is being debugged.
> - The foreground is not locked (see [LockSetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-locksetforegroundwindow)).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see `SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` in [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa)).
> - No menus are active.
>
> An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window ¹. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user.

<sup><sup>1</sup> this is what prevents the mail program example detailed above from happening.</sup>

A process that fulfills these criteria can also "share" its permission to set the foreground window with another process by calling [`AllowSetForegroundWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow#remarks)

---

##### SetActiveWindow

[`SetActiveWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setactivewindow) only works if the targeted window is attached to your message queue **and** one of your application windows is currently the foreground window.

> Activates a window. The window **must be attached to the calling thread's message queue**.
>
> The window will be brought into the foreground (top of Z-Order) **if its application is in the foreground when the system activates the window.**

---

##### BringWindowToTop

[`BringWindowToTop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-bringwindowtotop) is a convenience function for [`SetWindowPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos), which again has the same restrictions:

> If an application is not in the foreground, and should be in the foreground, it must call the [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) function.
>
> To use **SetWindowPos** to bring a window to the top, the process that owns the window must have [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) permission.

---

##### Using UI Automation

Since you mentioned that you need this functionality for an accessibility tool, here's how you could accomplish this using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32):

This example uses bare-bones COM for simplicity, but if you want you can of course use e.g. [`wil`](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) for a more C++-like API.

```cpp
#include <uiautomation.h>

bool MoveWindowToForeground(IUIAutomation* pAutomation, HWND hWnd) {
    // retrieve an ui automation handle for a given window
    IUIAutomationElement* element = nullptr;
    HRESULT result = pAutomation->ElementFromHandle(hWnd, &element);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    // move the window into the foreground
    result = element->SetFocus();

    // cleanup
    element->Release();
    return SUCCEEDED(result);
}

int main()
{
    // initialize COM, only needs to be done once per thread
    CoInitialize(nullptr);

    // create the UI automation object
    IUIAutomation* pAutomation = nullptr;
    HRESULT result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&pAutomation));
    if (FAILED(result))
        return 1;

    // move the given window into the foreground
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowW(nullptr, L"Calculator");
    MoveWindowToForeground(pAutomation, hWnd);
    
    // cleanup
    pAutomation->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and bypass those restrictions?

Comment: @RyanGlenn there are a few - but keep in mind that this will be very obnoxious for your users (and might not work in the future if Microsoft decides to change things) - those rules are there for a good reason. One way would be [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) which is intended for assistive technologies for people with disabilities (like e.g. screen readers) - which as such of course need to be able to bypass those restrictions.

Comment: This app is only a tool for myself. Part of why I want it to focus a specific window is because I get distracted a lot. This is to help me stay focused on what I need to be focused on. It's quite interesting you mention this because I have ADHD and that's exactly why I want to do this :D

Comment: @RyanGlenn Oh then that's a perfect use case for UI Automation :) [Here's a small example](https://godbolt.org/z/61W4vhzs3) of how it works. You only need to [create the automation object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-creatingcuiautomation), [get an automation element from your window handle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-elementfromhandle) and then [focus it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-setfocus).

Comment: With UI Automation, you don't need to use Windows APIs like FindWindowW anymore, you would get the top level window from the root element, using a property condition filter (based on name or something else).

Answer (score 5):

`SetForegroundWindow()` is the correct way to change the foreground window, **but** the thread that calls `SetForegroundWindow()` has to meet certain criteria for it to "work". If it does not meet the criteria, the window's taskbar button is flashed instead. This is by design. This is to protect the user from applications stealing focus and you should respect that.

See also:

- [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083)
- [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101125-00/?p=12203)

Comment: Zoom in particular seems to always stay on top somehow. It's really annoying

Comment: But also Youtube (the website through a browser) with "picture in picture" stays on top all the time. That's less annoying. How do they do that?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili There's a special window style for windows that should always stay on top: [`WS_EX_TOPMOST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles): »*The window should be placed above all non-topmost windows and should stay above them, even when the window is deactivated.*«

Comment: You can either directly pass it when creating the window in the `dwExStyle` parameter of [`CreateWindowEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa) or add it later with [`SetWindowLong()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga) using `GWL_EXSTYLE`.

Comment: @Turtlefight That's very interesting. Is there a size limit to such windows? What's stopping me from making my whole window one of those?